# How to make a calculator in Python 3

Tags: python, calculator

I need to create a calculator in Python that can perform all of these tasks. I have gotten this far with my code to do addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Can someone show me what to add to my code to add log, power, Pythagorean theorem, and factorial to my calculator? These are all the requirements for my calculator below.

Each mathematic operation needs to be its own function/method:
Addition - Takes up to 5 arguments,
Subtraction - - Takes 3 arguments,
Multiplication - Takes 4 arguments,
Division - Takes 2 arguments,
Log - Takes 1 argument,
Raise a number to a power ex. X squared,
Solve Pythagorean theorem,
Factorial

```
def calculate():
    operation = input('''
Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
''')

    number_1 = int(input('Please enter the first number: '))
    number_2 = int(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    if operation == '+':
        print('{} + {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 + number_2)

    elif operation == '-':
        print('{} - {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 - number_2)

    elif operation == '*':
        print('{} * {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 * number_2)

    elif operation == '/':
        print('{} / {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 / number_2)

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator, please run the program again.')

    # Add again() function to calculate() function
    again()

def again():
    calc_again = input('''
Do you want to calculate again?
Please type Y for YES or N for NO.
''')

    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculate()
    elif calc_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('See you later.')
    else:
        again()

calculate()
```

Comment: As a general practice, a while loop is preferred over your recursive input solution since a user using this implementation of the calculator will eventually reach the recursive limit.

Comment: All the implemented calculations so far take two arguments but you mention various values such as up to 5 for addition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This seems like homework. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) What do you need help with exactly? Like, to start, do you know how to do log, power, Pythagorean theorem, and factorial in Python? There should be existing questions that cover all of them. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the ideas of your requested functions. I added some of them to your calculator. You can also change the hints that you want to show to the user.

PS: Better to use `while` for the calculator loop.

```
import math

def calculate():
    operation = input('''
Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
! for factorial
log for logarithm(number, base)
hypot for Pythagorean
''')

    number_1 = int(input('Please enter the first number: '))
    number_2 = int(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    if operation == '+':
        print('{} + {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 + number_2)

    elif operation == '-':
        print('{} - {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 - number_2)

    elif operation == '*':
        print('{} * {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 * number_2)

    elif operation == '/':
        print('{} / {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 / number_2)

    elif operation == '!':
        print(math.factorial(number_1))
        print(math.factorial(number_2))

    elif operation == 'log':
        print(math.log(number_1, number_2))

    elif operation == 'hypot':
        print(math.hypot(number_1, number_2))

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator, please run the program again.')

    # Add again() function to calculate() function
    again()

def again():
    calc_again = input('''
Do you want to calculate again?
Please type Y for YES or N for NO.
''')

    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculate()
    elif calc_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('See you later.')
    else:
        again()

calculate()
```

I updated the answer based on the comment; you want to take a variable number of inputs from a user like `n` numbers. I used `add()` for your situation to answer your exact issue and removed additional codes.

```
def add(numbers_list):
    return sum(numbers_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while(True):
        number_of_inputs = int(input('Number of inputs? '))
        numbers = [float(input(f'Please enter a number({i + 1}): ')) for i in range(number_of_inputs)]
        print(add(numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you Iman I appreciate that, Currently revising my code now and also added the power operation for myself. One more quick question, dont mean to bother. How would I add more arguments for subtraction and multiplication. Would that mean adding a third number, fourth number etc.? Or is that not correct, do you mind correcting me if I am. @ImanShafiei